# How can I reduce App Engine billing cost?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

My app engine yaml file is somewhat like below

```
service: servicename
runtime: php74

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_pending_latency: 1s

env_variables:
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: <MY-PROJECT>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<MY-DATABASE>
  DB_USER: my-db-user
  DB_PASS: my-db-pass
  DB_NAME: my-db
 
---
```

automatic scaling cause higher cost? what is the cheapest configuration I can set. it's not mandatory to have auto scaling at current stage of my application.

Comment: Do you use flex or standard version of App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

I think your cheapest configuration is just setting `max_instances: 1` and commenting out the other options.

When you have traffic, the maximum number of instances that you will have will be 1. When there's no traffic, your instance goes down (effectively 0).

The downside with this approach (not having min_idle_instance as you currently do) is that brand new traffic to your site will take some time because of the time for your instance to be started.